# two transaction within one transaction hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm making the maintenance of a app with Struts 1, Spring 3 and Hibernate 3.
I want join two services, but each service have 1 transaction. The solution that i am thinking is make 1 service with 1 transaction that include the two services. It's possible this?

-The transaction located in the DAO's.

*Service Expediente:

```
public void saveExpedienteCoactivo(CoaTExpc coaTExpc, Auditoria auditoria, String numeracionAutomaticaExpediente) throws Exception, BusinessException{
    IExpedienteCoactivoDAO dao = (IExpedienteCoactivoDAO)getDao();
    try{
//business rules
dao.saveExpedienteCoactivo(coaTExpc, numeracionAutomaticaExpediente);
catch{...}
}
```

*DAO Expediente:

```
public synchronized void saveExpedienteCoactivo(CoaTExpc coaTExpc, String numeracionAutomaticaExpediente) throws Exception {
    Session sessionHibernate = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Savepoint savePoint = sessionHibernate.connection().setSavepoint();
    try{
sessionHibernate.saveOrUpdate(coaTExpc);
sessionHibernate.connection().commit();
}catch(Exception e) {
        sessionHibernate.connection().rollback(savePoint);
        sessionHibernate.getTransaction().rollback();
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+", Error="+e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

*Service Resolucion:

```
public void saveResolucion(CoaTRcoa coaTRcoa, Auditoria auditoria) throws Exception, BusinessException{
    IResolucionDAO dao = (IResolucionDAO)getDao();
    try{    
//business rules
dao.saveResolucion(coaTRcoa);
}catch{...}
}
```

*DAO Resolucion:

```
public synchronized void saveResolucion(CoaTRcoa coaTRcoa) throws Exception {
    Session sessionHibernate = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Savepoint savePoint = sessionHibernate.connection().setSavepoint();
    try{
//more code and sql here
sessionHibernate.saveOrUpdate(coaTRcoa);
//more code sql
sessionHibernate.connection().commit();     
}catch(Exception e) {
        sessionHibernate.connection().rollback(savePoint);
        sessionHibernate.getTransaction().rollback();
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+", Error="+e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

*applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:gob/osinerg/spjc/configuracion/domain/mapping</value>
            <value>classpath:gob/osinerg/spjc/notificaciones/domain/mapping</value>
            <value>classpath:gob/osinerg/spjc/judicial/domain/mapping</value>
            <value>classpath:gob/osinerg/spjc/coactiva/domain/mapping</value>
            <value>classpath:gob/osinerg/spjc/common/domain/mapping</value>
            <value>classpath:gob/osinerg/alfresco/domain/mapping</value>    
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>  

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txProxyTemplate" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref local="transactionManager"/>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="get*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="load*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
            <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="delete*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, It's possible this?

```
public class ServiceTransactionImp implements ServiceTransaction{
public void doTwoSaveTransaction(){
Session sessionHibernate = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Savepoint savePoint = sessionHibernate.connection().setSavepoint();
try{    
serviceExpediente.saveExpedienteCoactivo(coaTExpc,auditoria,numeracionAutomaticaExpediente);
serviceResolucion.saveResolucion(coaTRcoa,auditoria);
sessionHibernate.connection().commit();     
}catch(Exception e) {
        sessionHibernate.connection().rollback(savePoint);
        sessionHibernate.getTransaction().rollback();
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName()+", Error="+e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it works, because the session is distinct between the proceses and if the possible rollback of saveResolucion will affect to the service of saveExpedienteCoactivo as have a commit(); the idea is execute rollback to all the proceses.

Or any other solution?

Comment: It won't work as your setup is flawed, you are committing and you cannot commit persisted data. Why aren't you using declarative transactions instead of doing things manually?

Comment: The app is configured by xml, but this don't use annotations.

Comment: So? You can still do declarative transactions in xml you don't need annotations for that. You could do declarative transactions 10 years ago with spring and that still works.

Comment: Then, my solution is possible applying declarative transaction by xml. Can you give me any link or example with spring and hibernate? Thanks